# Is there any animal internal monologue in The Lord of the Rings?

Tags: j-r-r-tolkien, the-lord-of-the-rings

Does Tolkien ever include any internal monologue from the perspective of an animal? That is to say, a scene where he shows an animal talking to itself inside of its own head?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes. When leaving the Shire, the hobbits disturbed a fox:

> A fox passing through the wood on business of his own stopped several minutes and sniffed.
>
> 'Hobbits!' he thought. 'Well, what next? I have heard of strange doings in this land, but I have seldom heard of a hobbit sleeping out of doors under a tree. Three of them! There's something mighty queer behind this.' He was quite right, but he never found out any more about it.
>
> <sub>-- *The Fellowship of the Ring*, Chapter 3: "Three is Company"</sub>

Answer (score -1):

If I remember correctly, Shelob the sentient spider has a few inner-monologue moments.

Also, if you're interested about regular animals showing sentience in general, in The Hobbit, a Thrush and a Raven communicate with the Dwarves when on the Lonely Mountain. The Raven, if I recall correctly, tried to communicate and wasn't understood by the dwarves, but understood the dwarves' speaking about needing a Thrush, and the Thrush spoke with one of the dwarves who could interpret.

Comment: If you can find those moments from Shelob, quoting them would improve this answer. (Although I'm not sure if a superintelligent supermassive monster really counts as a normal enough animal to fit the scope of the question.)